# How to stop debug without closing app in Android Studio 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

when I debugging my application and if I click on th Stop button -

[image]

- debugging stopped work - and! - my application closing. (I think android studio just kills proccess).

How can I stop debugging without stopping process?

Answer (score 11):

Press the `Close` button:

[image]

then press `Disconnect` in the dialog, paying attention to leave unchecked `Terminate the process after disconnect`:

[image]

Comment: It closes the app for me

Answer (score 0):

Try another way.

First "Mute Breakpoints", then in debugger console, choose "Step Out" and "Run to Cursor".

[image]