# How to stop Android app built in Android Studio from waiting for debugger attaching?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

After I started to use debugging with attaching debugger in Android Studio, I cannot install standalone package - it says "Waiting for debugger to attach" ! I cannot run program in another way, rather than from Android Studio itself! Same thing happens, if I press "Run" - than, even worse, it is waiting for debugger that is not even going to attach...

*Note:*
I have also seen this question:
[How to stop debug without closing app in Android Studio 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647707/how-to-stop-debug-without-closing-app-in-android-studio-2)
 - However, in my case there is no stop button! I just disconnect

Comment: uninstall that apk manually from device and try installing it fresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do one of either**:

1. You have either accidentally set a breakpoint by misclicking either Ctrl + F8 or simply left clicking the line-count. So look through your code for that.

   - Tip: If you are unsure about this, create a new project and install it, if it works, this is most likely the error you are facing.
2. You have selected an app to be debugged. Go to your phone's settings -> Developer Options -> Select app to be debugged -> No apps. This will clear it.
3. Restart your phone.
4. Uninstall your apk and reinstall it fresh again.

Comment: Eh, this doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ohhhh my apologies, are you running it on your mobile device? IF you are then go to your phone's settings -> Developer Options -> Select app to be debugged -> No apps

Comment: Did this work? Also, if it's already "No apps" then just restart the device, also make sure you do not have any breakpoints in your code. If you are unsure of break points then just check if the problem is solved with a fresh new project. If it is, then you most likely have a breakpoint in your code and you acidentally either pressed ctrl+F8 or left clicked on the left side of your code where it says the line count.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that was debugging app in tablet settings. Stupid me, forgot about that :)